# How to check syslog in Bash on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, syslog

In C we log this way:

```
syslog( LOG_INFO, "proxying %s", url );
```

In Linux how can we check the log?

Comment: Doesn't the function `syslog` *write* to the system log? (Unless you're talking about the lower-level one for accessing the kernel message ring buffer, but I doubt `url` is an `int`.)

Comment: this Q should be migrated to unix.SE.com, not sure if it's worth it to flag for mod's attention (I flagged).

Answer (score 204, accepted):

How about `less /var/log/syslog`?

Comment: @kern: Which linux distro and version are you using?

Comment: @kern: Check out the contents of your `/etc/syslog.conf`

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/syslog` is really nice because it shows the most recent output as it goes into the syslog. It can be useful if you're trying to troubleshoot something live, rather than look at something that's strictly in the past.

Comment: it's actually /etc/rsyslog.conf for CentOs

Comment: But only root user has the permission to read /var/log/syslog by default. Any other way??

Comment: @ArunprasadRajkumar The other way would be to avoid logging messages meant to be read by normal users to  syslog

Answer (score 48):

On Fedora 19, it looks like the answer is `/var/log/messages`. Although check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` if it has been changed.

Comment: I've checked it on openSUSE and noticed it applies to it too. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Also for CentOS

Answer (score 41):

By default it's logged into system log at `/var/log/syslog`, so it can be read by:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

If the file doesn't exist, check `/etc/syslog.conf` to see configuration file for syslogd.
Note that the configuration file could be different, so check the running process if it's using different file:

```
# ps wuax | grep syslog
root      /sbin/syslogd -f /etc/syslog-knoppix.conf
```

<sup>Note: In some distributions (such as Knoppix) all logged messages could be sent into different terminal (e.g. `/dev/tty12`), so to access e.g. `tty12` try  pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.</sup>

You can also use `lsof` tool to find out which log file the `syslogd` process is using, e.g.

```
sudo lsof -p $(pgrep syslog) | grep log$
```

---

To send the test message to syslogd in shell, you may try:

```
echo test | logger
```

---

For troubleshooting use a trace tool (`strace` on Linux, `dtruss` on Unix), e.g.:

```
sudo strace -fp $(cat /var/run/syslogd.pid)
```

Answer (score 28):

A very cool util is `journalctl`.

For example, to show syslog to console: `journalctl -t <syslog-ident>`, where `<syslog-ident>` is identity you gave to function `openlog` to initialize syslog.

Comment: If you use `syslog-ng` with the systemd service, you can view syslog with `journalctl --unit=syslog-ng@default.service`

Comment: This should be marked as right answer, instead cat a specific distro and configuration filename and filtering with grep.

Answer (score 15):

`tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep process_name`
where `process_name` is the name of the process we are interested in

Answer (score 4):

If you like Vim, it has built-in syntax highlighting for the syslog file, e.g. it will highlight error messages in red.

```
vi +'syntax on' /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 3):

On some Linux systems (e.g. Debian and Ubuntu) syslog is rotated daily and you have multiple log files where two newest files are uncompressed while older ones are compressed:

```
$ ls -l /var/log/syslog*
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  888238 Aug 25 12:02 /var/log/syslog
-rw-r----- 1 root adm 1438588 Aug 25 00:05 /var/log/syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   95161 Aug 24 00:07 /var/log/syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  103829 Aug 23 00:08 /var/log/syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm   82679 Aug 22 00:06 /var/log/syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  270313 Aug 21 00:10 /var/log/syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  110724 Aug 20 00:09 /var/log/syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  178880 Aug 19 00:08 /var/log/syslog.7.gz
```

To search all the syslog files you can use the following commands:

```
$ sudo zcat -f `ls -tr /var/log/syslog*` | grep -i error | less
```

where **zcat** first decompresses and prints all syslog files (oldest first), **grep** makes a search and **less** is paging the results of the search.

To do the same but with the lines prefixed with the name of the syslog file you can use **zgrep**:

```
$ sudo zgrep -i error `ls -tr /var/log/syslog*` | less

$ zgrep -V | grep zgrep
zgrep (gzip) 1.6
```

In both cases **sudo** is required if syslog files are not readable by ordinary users.