# How to login to mail to send patches using git

Tags: linux, git

I want to send patches to the mailing list and my git config file is like the below.

My git config --list looks like:

```
user.name=xxx.
user.email=xxx@abc.com
sendemail.smtpserver=mail.abc.com
sendemail.smtpserverport=587
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

I get the following error, it could help if someone can help in clearing this.
Error:

```
You must log in to send mail from abc.com
```

Comment: What distro and version are you using?

Comment: @bk2204   ,git version 2.20.1, Debain based distributiion.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a SMTP server error (as [seen for instance in citadel](https://github.com/mingodad/citadel/blob/63a41edbab07ba009a64ece492c41282c654c58b/citadel/modules/smtp/serv_smtp.c#L691-L700))

```c
/* Otherwise, make sure outsiders aren't trying to forge mail from
     * this system (unless, of course, c_allow_spoofing is enabled)
     */
    else if (CtdlGetConfigInt("c_allow_spoofing") == 0) {
        process_rfc822_addr(ChrPtr(sSMTP->from), user, node, name);
        SMTP_syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Claimed envelope sender is '%s' == '%s' @ '%s' ('%s')",
            ChrPtr(sSMTP->from), user, node, name
        );
        if (CtdlHostAlias(node) != hostalias_nomatch) {
            cprintf("550 You must log in to send mail from %s\r\n", node);
```

[Check the syslog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074362/how-to-check-syslog-in-bash-on-linux) for a "Claimed envelope sender" message: that will give you a clue regarding your email mis-configuration.